# Clave foranea tabla - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una tabla en Oracle SQL, y un campo, quiero que sea clave foránea de la misma tabla, pero Oracle me da error.

```
create table Empleado_almacen
(
cod_empleado_almacen int,
dni varchar2(9),
dni_jefe varchar2(9),
nombre varchar2(30),
direccion varchar2(50),
sueldo number(4,1),
telefono number(9),
cod_almacen int,
constraint pk_empleado_almacen primary key(cod_empleado_almacen),

constraint fk_empleado_almacen_jefe foreign key (dni_jefe) 
    references Empleado_almacen(dni_jefe)
        on delete cascade,

constraint fk_almacen_empleado_almacen foreign key (cod_almacen) 
    references Almacen(cod_almacen)
        on delete cascade
);
```

No sé si el error es exactamente sobre la clave foránea, yo creo que sí, os escribo el error también:

```
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-02270: no hay ninguna clave única o primaria correspondiente 
para esta lista de columnas
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
       gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
       key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
       catalog view
```

Comment: Creo que tu error es porque para ser clave foranea debe ser tambien clave de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

El error te sale porque la columna **dni_jefe** no es una **clave primaría**. 
Me imagino que lo que estas buscando con esa clave foránea es indicar qué empleado es el jefe del actual, para ello tenes que usar **cod_empleado_almacen** como referencia en la relación.

```
constraint fk_empleado_almacen_jefe foreign key (dni_jefe) 
references Empleado_almacen(cod_empleado_almacen)
    on delete cascade,
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante claro, en alguna de las dos tablas que quieres hacer la referencia FK no esta declarada como clave primaria.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que habéis contestado, al final lo solucioné, dejo aquí la solución por si alguien la necesita.

```
create table Empleado_almacen
(
cod_empleado_almacen int,
dni varchar2(9),
jefe varchar2(2),
nombre varchar2(30),
direccion varchar2(50),
sueldo number(4,1),
telefono number(9),
cod_almacen int,
constraint pk_empleado_almacen primary key(cod_empleado_almacen),

constraint fk_empleado_almacen_jefe foreign key (cod_empleado_almacen) 
    references Empleado_almacen(cod_empleado_almacen)
        on delete cascade,

constraint fk_almacen_empleado_almacen foreign key (cod_almacen) 
    references Almacen(cod_almacen)
        on delete cascade
);
```